# How Do I Dismiss My Login View For Good?

Tags: ios, authentication, modalviewcontroller

so far i have gotten my login view to appear at the at the start of the app by using a method in viewDidAppear in my first view controller, but once the username and password gets approved by the web service, the 1st view controller appears for a split second and than immediately goes back to the login view.

am i forgetting something??? i only did coding in my login view, and my 1st view.

coding for the 1st :

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

heres the coding in my loginview

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{ 
    NSMutableString *Yes =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Y"];

    if ([ capturedCharacters isEqualToString:Yes])
    {
            //[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
    }
    else
    {
        // ask user to login again, 
    }

   [capturedCharacters release];
    capturedCharacters = nil;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"str_partinfo"]) {
        // We are no longer in an item element
        inItemElement = NO;

    }
}
```

and I'm using a tab bar template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

You're  presenting the loginView every single time your parent view controller comes into view. I think what's actually happening is that when the login view gets dismissed, "viewDidAppear" fires which calls the login view again.

Try putting the logic inside -(void)viewDidLoad and see if this does the trick:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
     UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
     [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

     [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }
```

Alternatively, you can have a BOOL pointer, pseudocode:

```
 BOOL loginSuccessful;
 if(!loginSuccessful)
 {
      //ShowLogin
      loginSuccessful = TRUE;

 }
```